# GRPC C# Library For a Windows 8.1 Phone App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, grpc

Is it possible to use [GRPC C# library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc/) with a Windows Phone App? When I try to install GRPC through NuGet I receive the following error:

> Error     Could not install package 'Grpc.Core 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhoneApp,Version=v8.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.            0

Has anyone had any luck installing GRPC C# library for a windows phone app?

Comment: It doesn't support it.

Comment: Do you know why this is the case? Is it possible to compile the GRPC library from source and target the Windows Phone?

Comment: A rough guess is that it's simply by abandoned by everyone, including Microsoft :)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Windows Phone Apps are not supported by gRPC C#. Technically, supporting them would be possible but we are not sure it's worth the work at this point - we have different priorities (User experience, performance and supporting other platforms).

Here's a github issue that tracks the discussion: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/7859